# Nginx - How to get variable which is number from url & set it to a variable?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm trying to create a config for fileuploads by getting their ids from the url.

Example url:
`example.com/fileupload/123`

This will upload the images to the `123` folder.

Current config:

```
location /fileupload/(^[0-9]+$)$ {
           if ($request_method = 'POST') {
              add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
              add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
              add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range,fileheader';
              add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
           }
            default_type text/html;
            set $fileSavePath "C:\\server\\openresty\\user\\images\\"+$1;
            content_by_lua_file lua/fileupload.lua;
        }
```

My config seems to not be working after reloading.
Basically I'm trying to get the numbers from the url, then add it to my existing path variable.

Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

As I remember there is no string concatenation in Nginx, so you can't merge strings using +

Just write is as

```
    $fileSavePath "C:\\server\\openresty\\user\\images\\$1"
```